# Extract text from html file with BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the text from a html file.
The `html` file looks like this:

```html
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-1">
    <a href="#Baden-Württemberg"><span class="tocnumber">1</span>
        <span class="toctext">Baden-Württemberg</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-2">
    <a href="#Bayern">
        <span class="tocnumber">2</span>
        <span class="toctext">Bayern</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-3">
    <a href="#Berlin">
        <span class="tocnumber">3</span>
        <span class="toctext">Berlin</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I want to extract the last text from the last `span`tag.
In the first line it would be "Baden-Würtemberg" after  `class="toctext"`and then put it to a python list.

in Python I tried the following:

```
names = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"toctext"})
```

My output the is this `list`:

```
[<span class="toctext">Baden-Württemberg</span>, <span class="toctext">Bayern</span>, <span class="toctext">Berlin</span>]
```

So how can I extract only the text between the tags?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find_all` method returns a list. Iterate over the list to get the text.

```
for name in names:
    print(name.text)
```

Returns:

```
Baden-Württemberg
Bayern
Berlin
```

The builtin python `dir()` and `type()` methods are always handy to inspect an object.

```
print(dir(names))

[...,
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'append',
 'clear',
 'copy',
 'count',
 'extend',
 'index',
 'insert',
 'pop',
 'remove',
 'reverse',
 'sort',
 'source']
```

Answer (score 0):

With a list of comprehension you could do the following :

```
names = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"toctext"})
print([x.text for x in names])
```