# Python BeautifulSoup: How to get TEXT from <td>TEXT</td>

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i can't figure it out how to get TEXT and NUMBERS from this tag `<td>THERE IS TEXT I WANT TO GET</td>` and there is "Quantity" also with `<td>QUANTITY</td>`

`link:https://bscscan.com/tokenholdings?a=0x00a2c3d755c21bc837a3ca9a32279275eae9e3d6`

there is image what i want to get.

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `page = requests.get("https://bscscan.com/tokenholdings?a=0x4E93eDBf26744e36D8E34E267c0F22587bd5a329")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table' ,attrs={'class':'table-active'})
first_td = table.find('td')
text = first_td.renderContents()
trimmed_text = text.strip()

print(trimmed_text)`

Comment: [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62384301/python-beautiful-soup-get-text-from-element)

Comment: @Ghonghito You can't scrape the table using ```requests```. Check out my solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract text from html file with BeautifulSoup/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691423/extract-text-from-html-file-with-beautifulsoup-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table in the website is loaded dynamically, so you can't scrape it using `requests`. You have to use `selenium` in order to do it. Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://bscscan.com/tokenholdings?a=0x00a2c3d755c21bc837a3ca9a32279275eae9e3d6'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

html = driver.page_source

driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

tbody = soup.find('tbody', id = "tb1")

tr_tags = tbody.find_all('tr')

symbols = []
quantities = []

for tr in tr_tags:
    td_tags = tr.find_all('td')
    symbols.append(td_tags[2].text)
    quantities.append(td_tags[3].text)

df = pd.DataFrame((symbols,quantities))

df = df.T

df.columns = ['Symbol','Quantity']

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Symbol      Quantity
0    BNB   17.98420742
1   Cake   19.76899295
2    ANY             1
3   FREE         1,502
4    LFI  326.87340092
5    LFI  326.87340092
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a really good tool called re, and you can search the specific string from two substrings, e.g.

```
import re

s = ''<td>THERE IS TEXT I WANT TO GET</td>"
result = re.search('<td>(.*)</td>', s)
print(result.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> html="<td>THERE IS TEXT I WANT TO GET</td>\n<td>THERE IS TEXT I WANT TO GET</td>\n<td>THERE IS TEXT I WANT TO GET</td>\n<td>THERE IS TEXT I WANT TO GET</td>"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> for td in soup.find_all('td'): print(td.text)
```